# How do I set selectedItem and bind to it with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a list as follows:

```
<ul id="blogList" data-bind="foreach: Data">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: Title"> </span>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.viewEntry">View</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And knockout view model as below:

```
var ViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

    this.currentSelected = ko.observable();

    self.viewEntry = function () {
        currentSelected = this;
    }
};
```

Setting the currentSelected to this doesn't seem to work because when I try to bind to currentSelected somewhere else I get nothing happening:

```
<h2 data-bind="text: currentSelected.Title"></h2>
```

Is that the correct way to bind to currentSelected? The list is working fine but setting the currentSelected and binding to it isn't working.

Comment: currentSelected = this; will only assign the current context to currentSelected nothing else. No value

Comment: How do I pass in the selected item to the viewEntry function?

Comment: what do you mean by selected items ? are li items selected ?

Comment: The blogList has a list of items displayed. I want to set currentSelected to the one being clicked: `<a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.viewEntry">View</a>`

Comment: you can use a bit of jquery to get the data inside click function. by doing something like $(this).text() and why you are using a tag inside li ?

Comment: It is like example 2 here: [link](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's have a look at your `viewEntry` method.

```
    self.viewEntry = function () {
        currentSelected = this;
    }
```

`currentSelected` is undefined it should be `self.currentSelected` additionally since this is an observable you should not set this as `var` with equal sign but rather treat this as function so it should be `self.currentSelected(this)`

the other thing is binding inside this part:

```
<h2 data-bind="text: currentSelected.Title"></h2>
```

again this is an object so to access its properties you need to use `currentSelected` as function so it should be

```
<h2 data-bind="text: currentSelected().Title"></h2>
```

Here you can find a working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/jz9t5vbo/